Preserve leading white space (indents) in Azure Data Studio XML output
By default Azure Data Studio seems to remove leading whitespace from the inner text in XML columns in the results of a query.  Is there any way to preserve the leading whitespace in XML inner text?
Example:
declare @xml xml = 
'<root>
    <text>
Unindented text.
    Single indented text.
        Double-indented text.
    </text>
</root>';

select @xml;

Result, after clicking on the XML output column in the result pane to open the XML in a separate window:

Desired result (mockup):

I've tried unchecking setting Query Editor > Results > Save as Xml: Formatted but that doesn't make any difference so I assume it's for saving the results to a file.

The current Xml version has by default ability to Format the XML data type column or the XML data containing varchar data type column.
you can see here the bug fixes in current releases.

Query Editor > Results > Save as Xml: Formatted
The option you explored in the settings will work when you save the result set in XML format.

Thanks @PratikLad.  I'm looking for a way to preserve the leading whitespace when displaying XML in the app, rather than when saving to a file.  I find it easier to copy and paste from the app, rather than saving the XML as a file then having to find the file, open it, and copy its contents.
